Infinite derivative at zero bundle
I'm a first year grad student and something we've been using to ensure a maximization problem doesn't admit $0 \in \mathbb R^d$ as a solution is that the derivative (gradient) of the production/utility function is infinite at 0. As intuitive as this is, I haven't found anything that proves that it actually works. Does anyone know any references that do it? Thanks in advance.

See Inada conditions

The Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem would work, because
$$
\frac{\partial f(\mathbb{x})}{\partial x_i} + \mathbb{\lambda} \frac{\partial \mathbb{g}(\mathbb{x})}{\partial x_i} = 0
$$
implies
$$
\frac{\partial f(\mathbb{x})}{\partial x_i} \neq \infty,
$$
since the budget, technology etc. constraints have finite slopes1 and $\lambda$ is a real-valued vector.

1 The 'maximization problem' is not defined in the question, but these constraints are usually linear.
